# How to replicate type registration in autofac configuration file

Tags: autofac

I have a test application that performs autofac registration of components and sub-components in code and it works as expected and desired.  However, I would like to move that registration to an external configuration file to allow for easier extensibility of the subsystem that is being built.

Below is a sample from the current code:

```
        builder.RegisterType<DefaultWriter>()
            .Named<IWriter>("DefaultWriter");

        builder.RegisterType<SQLWriter>()
            .Named<IWriter>("SQLWriter");

        builder.RegisterType<DefaultEncryptor>()
            .Named<IEncryptor>("DefaultEncryptor");

        builder.RegisterType<SuperEncryptor>()
            .Named<IEncryptor>("SuperEncryptor");

        builder.RegisterType<Logger>()
            .Named<ILogger>("StandardLogger")
            .WithParameter(Autofac.Core.ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IEncryptor>("DefaultEncryptor"))
            .WithParameter(Autofac.Core.ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IWriter>("DefaultWriter"));

        builder.RegisterType<Logger>()
            .Named<ILogger>("ActivityLogger")
            .WithParameter(Autofac.Core.ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IEncryptor>("DefaultEncryptor"))
            .WithParameter(Autofac.Core.ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IWriter>("SQLWriter"));

        builder.RegisterType<Logger>()
            .Named<ILogger>("CyberLogger")
            .WithParameter(Autofac.Core.ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IEncryptor>("SuperEncryptor"))
            .WithParameter(Autofac.Core.ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<IWriter>("SQLWriter"));
```

I would like to drop this into app.config so that when new components are developed that it is easier to deploy them (just the code module and some config settings).  I have this as a start but not sure how or if I can replicate the .WithParameter statements from the code.

```
<components>
  <!-- type=Library for adapter (namespace and classname, DLL name),  service=Library for common interface (namespace, DLL name)-->
  <component 
    name="DefaultWriter" 
    type="CommonWriter.DefaultWriter, CommonWriter" 
    service="LoggerInterfaces.IWriter, LoggerInterfaces" />

  <component 
    name="SQLWriter" 
    type="CommonWriter.SQLWriter, CommonWriter" 
    service="LoggerInterfaces.IWriter, LoggerInterfaces" />

  <component 
    name="DefaultEncryptor" 
    type="CommonEncryptor.DefaultEncryptor, CommonEncryptor" 
    service="LoggerInterfaces.IEncryptor, LoggerInterfaces" />

  <component 
    name="SuperEncryptor" 
    type="CustomEncryptor.SuperEncryptor, CustomEncryptor" 
    service="LoggerInterfaces.IEncryptor, LoggerInterfaces" />

  <component 
    name="StandardLogger" 
    type="CommonLogger.Logger, CommonLogger" 
    service="LoggerInterfaces.ILogger, LoggerInterfaces" >
    <parameters>
    </parameters>
  </component>

</components>
```

That is as far as I have gotten.  Am I locked into doing this in code or am I missing something obvious?

Thanks